# How to filter except users which already has been liked?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filter

I'm trying to filter all users except current user liked people. `liked` is an array. `allUsers` is an array too. I have filtered that if user is logged in, he can't see him self in date app displayed users. But filter out those users which user already liked, it's harder.. There's my code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        async function currentUser() {
            const resp = await get(`user/${localSecret}`)
            setCurrent(resp.data)
        }
        currentUser()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchUsers() {
            const resp = await get(`api`)
            // Filter out current user from displayed users
            const filter = resp.filter(user => user.secret !== localSecret)
            getAllUsers(filter)
        }
        fetchUsers()
    }, [])
```

```js
  useEffect(() => {
        async function getAllUsers() {
            const resp = await get('api')
            // Here I'm trying to filter out already liked users
            // current.liked is an array of users objects
            const filtered = resp.filter(user => user !== current.liked)
            setAllUsers(filtered)
        }
        getAllUsers()
    }, [])
```

This is mongodb user liked array of objects, to make simplier to understand:
[image]

Comment: You can try to filter with the ID of `current.liked` like so 

`const filtered = resp.filter(user => current.liked.find((liked) => liked !== user.id))`

if I'm getting what you want to achieve correctly this should work. you can use underscore to always verify its object properties. 

it's hacky but should work. you can also move this logic to a useCallback

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter with the ID of `current.liked` like so

```js
const filtered = resp.filter(user => !current.liked.includes(user))
setAllUsers(filtered)
```

if I'm getting what you want to achieve correctly this should work. you can use `underscore` to always verify its object properties. it's hacky but should work. you can also move this logic to a useCallback

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna try it now, I'll let you know how it's worked!

Comment: Well.. It's not working, still getting liked users..